# Attach single log file once per pytest run in allure testops

Tags: pytest, allure

How to attach whole local log file at the end of PyTest run for allure report? I'm able to dissect log file with custom decorator, but developers want a whole log file to easily grep necessary debug information.

Answer (score 0):

save it to a file and add as an attachment

```
@allure.story("smoking pytest")
@allure.feature("sending attachments")
@allure.title("Sending 200+ Kbytes attachment")
def test_attach_normalimage():
    with allure.step("Sending normal 240 kbytes JPG attach"):
        allure.attach.file(os.path.join("resources", "normal-image.jpg"), name="240 Kb JPG example", attachment_type=attachment_type.JPG)
    with allure.step("HTML attach"):
        allure.attach("<h1>Example html attachment</h1>", name="HTML example", attachment_type=attachment_type.HTML)
    with allure.step("txt attach"):
        allure.attach("Some text content", name="TXT example", attachment_type=attachment_type.TEXT)
    with allure.step("CSV attach"):
        allure.attach('first,second,third\none,two,three', name="CSV example", attachment_type=attachment_type.CSV)
    with allure.step("JSON attach"):
        allure.attach(json.dumps({"first": 1, "second": 2}, indent=2),name="JSON example", attachment_type=attachment_type.JSON)
    with allure.step("URI list attach"):        
        allure.attach("\n".join(["https://github.com/allure-framework", "https://github.com/allure-examples"]), name="URI List example", attachment_type=attachment_type.URI_LIST)
```